# Creating an observable in Javascript which resolves once methods returns value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2-observables

To refresh an access_token which automatically expires, I need a function which makes a refresh_token call the first time it gets called, but waits for this first call to complete before making a second call.

In case the app is busy requesting a token, I would like it to wait until a certain function returns a value (i.e. not null). I believe this should be possible with Observables.

So far, I have an observable which reads my storage folder, but I don't know how to make it wait for a response on the storage.get() function.

```
Observable.create(observer => observer.next(this.storage.get('accessToken'));
```

Comment: am not sure how to implement but you can use generators

Comment: Does your `storage.get()` call return a promise?

Comment: No, it returns the value a string

Comment: So it's a synchronous call? If so, I'm confused about what you're waiting on.

Comment: I want storage.get() to wait for the response of the first call. Currenty, the second call will return "null", before the first call sets the correct value.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. So the first call is async. Is it promise-based, or are you passing it a callback?